# Printable and reusable whiteboard material

Tags: materials

I'm trying to find a material suitable to be printed and with the properties of whiteboard, easy to clean and reusable. I'm having difficulties to find alternative materials, or providers.

As far as I know [magic whiteboard](http://www.magicwhiteboard.co.uk/) is an alternative but it isn't reusable, only last two times.

**EDIT**

When I say printable I mean than I can print on it, lines or other shapes and images like on paper and I want this to be permanent. I didn't mean that it needs to be printed in a 3D printer, sorry.

Maybe I'm looking for simple whiteboard, but I need to print on it and make it lightweight and handy (mobile phone size). In addition I would like to be able to use different and thinner pens on it.

Comment: Just for clarification with your edit: you want a material that behaves like whiteboard. But you want to be able to permanently mark it before anyone ever uses it like a whiteboard. Is that correct? So print permanent marks first, then write temporary marks later?

Comment: @starrise Yes, that is correct. Thank you for your comment, that is an option. The main problem is that I'm having difficulties to find alternative materials, or providers, so I can make it handy (work with the size and the material).

Comment: related: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2194/which-material-should-i-use-for-a-whiteboard-that-would-erase-easily

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get a print on whatever material is easily available from local print houses. Either rigid or poster.

Install a glass screen in front of it, and you have your easily cleanable surface.

Comment: Clever idea, thank you @jpa. Do you know any kind of glass or sustitutive? Easy to work with.

Comment: @Kevin Normal plate glass is pretty easy to work with. You can probably even find ready-made photo frames that fit your purpose.

Comment: I _believe_ plexiglass is also easily re-writable in this manner, but scratches more readily than glass due to other contact and can become hazy. Glass is of course more durable but also heavier and shatters more easily. I beleve plexiglass is a bit less costly as well. Some pros and cons to help make a decision.

Answer (score 2):

I would think that the plastic (vinyl?) that print shops use for banners could be used for this purpose. We know that it is able to be printed on. The only unknown (to me) is how easily it can be erased. My impression is that any slick and flat surface should work for dry erase markers.

Another point in its favor is that it is durable. Being hung up outside for long periods of time has to be a more harsh use than rubbing on it with an eraser.

Comment: I think some of these banners have reinforcing material that makes them "bumpy," so OP might want to beware of that.

Answer (score 0):

I use polycarbonate film which is used for binding manuals. Polyvinyl chloride sheets are equally good but when using whiteboard markets you must encaustic they are stressed within 24 hours to avoid nasty stains